# Docker: Cargo.toml not found

Tags: docker, rust-cargo

I have a Cargo project with the following structure:

```
experiment
|
|- Dockerfile
|- Cargo.toml
|- src/
|-- main.rs
```

The contents of my Dockerfile are ([source](https://github.com/Scorpil/docker-rust/blob/master/1.10/onbuild/Dockerfile)):

```
FROM scorpil/rust:1.10

RUN mkdir -p /rust/app
WORKDIR /rust/app

ONBUILD COPY . /rust/app
OBUILD CMD ls -a /source
ONBUILD RUN cargo build --release

CMD cargo run --release
```

I've managed to build the image but when I try to run it on my local machine, I get the following error:

> docker run -i -d -p 8080:80 --name rust_hello_world
>   menawi/rust_hello_world

```
517a8772100cbd6fd388df1f3767175113ce2dbad93d144976b59d63d4809146
```

> docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
517a8772100c        menawi/rust_hello_world   "/bin/sh -c 'cargo ru"   17 seconds ago      Exited (101) 11 seconds ago                       rust_hello_world
```

> docker logs rust_hello_world

```
error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/rust/app` or any parent directory
```

Why do I get this error? Is there a way I can see which files were copied into the /rust/app folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can run container and override `CMD` with `bash` like

`docker run -i -t -p 8080:80 --name rust_hello_world menawi/rust_hello_world bash`

than you are in the bash of container and you can print list of files in the folder